# What's the Delphi equivalent to C++'s "unsigned char"?

Tags: c++, delphi

How can I convert the following C++ code to Delphi? In particular, what is `isenable`? I am trying to find out if this value is being added.

```
unsigned char isenable = 0;
if (m_Isbuzzer)
{
    isenable = isenable | 0x01;
}
if (m_Isled)
{
    isenable = isenable | 0x02;
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/veRcYK6c, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Talk:Delphi_to_C%2B%2B_types_mapping

Comment: Thank you TLama, I am missing to translate: 
 int data = _ttoi(m_Strtag.GetBuffer(0)); 
is this value in the buffer or what does this code means? user734781

Comment: `m_Strtag.GetBuffer(0)` is a method call. But that is a new question again. Do not followup with such new questions in comments.

Comment: @user you've placed this comment in the wrong question. Also _ttoi is documented. Did you search for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, `char` is an 8 bit type, and `unsigned` means, well, unsigned. Typically, `unsigned char` is used for binary byte oriented data. So map `unsigned char` to `Byte`. The excellent article that Rudy Velthuis wrote, [Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html), contains this information.

The `|` operator is bitwise OR. The C++ operators are listed and well documented here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Operators In Delphi bitwise OR is the [`or` operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Logical_.28Bitwise.29_Operators).

So the code would be:

```
var
  isenable: Byte;
....
isenable := 0;
if IsBuzzer then
  isenable := isenable or $01;
if IsLED then
  isenable := isenable or $02;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Can you please explain what does $01 stand for, is it a 1?

Comment: Have you read Rudy's article? Have you read the Delphi documentation? The `$` is well documented. It is the prefix that indicates a hexadecimal literal.

Comment: Documentation here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Numerals

Comment: @user734781 So, what more do you need here?

Comment: FWIW, see [The Help Vampire: A Spotter's Guide](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm). User734781 shows more and more of the behaviour described, including new questions in comments.

Comment: I meant [this answer from Meta-SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258279/95954): "Will continue to extend the original question with continued questions, even after the original question has been well answered.", etc.